# Stripping content from HTML page returned through ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery

Is there a way to display specific text out of a HTML page which was returned by an ajax call? By specific text, I mean the first paragraph/div of the HTML page returned.

By using [$.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) in jquery, I am able to fetch the page. How do I proceed from here.

Is it even possible to implement this using jQuery alone, without parsing html at the back end , and returning selected text as the response from my server.

Comment: Yes, you can use jquery to grab the contents that appear between the first div tags it finds. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I don't understand why the question has been voted down - it seems perfectly reasonable to me.  The OP is asking a question for which they don't know the answer.  Be fair..

Answer (score 2):

[.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) accepts a selector which can be used to specify the [fragment of the page](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments) to be appended

```
$('#x').load('page.html div:eq(0)')
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yIpp5krCVXnUDo5jhUgK?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

```
$.get("/mypage.html",function(html){
    var fisrtdiv = $('div',$(html)).first();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

$.load returns the whole html page unless you specify a fragment of it (as seen in another answer here).  You might be better off using $.get or $.ajax and then dealing with the returned data using a function:-

E.g. using ajax

```
$.ajax({
   url: "your url here",
   success: function(data) {
      //Do something with your data (ie the returned html).
   }
})
```

Comment: Is there a performance issue with $.load() compared to $.get/$.ajax?

Comment: Performance between the two will be more or less identical, I think.  The advantage of using $.ajax is that you can do more with the returned data if you want/need to at some point.  It's more flexible, wheras $.load will always just return html, whether filtered by a css selector or not.